# Solving Complex SQL-Based Aggregation problem with multiple events

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, pivot, rdbms

Long story short I failed the following test assessment a while ago. Want to finally understand how to solve it.

player_id : int
game_id : int
event_type : varchar(64)
event_time : timestamp

**store_game_install**: the specified player has performed an initial install of the specified game

**store_game_update**: the specified player has performed an update of the specified game

**store_open**: the specified player has launched the game store client on the device
**store_deleted**: the specified player has uninstalled the game store client on the device
**store_game_download**: the specified player has downloaded the game package onto
Since actual game install has to be inferred from a store_game_view followed by a store_game_download.

On the other hand, later versions of the store client have stopped producing the store_game_download event.

I had to construct a single MySql/PostgreSQL statement producing the following aggregation:

> game_id => game id
>
> game_views => Total count of game detail views for this
>
> game_installs => Total count of game installs for this game

ANY help would mean the world. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation.

In Postgres:

```
select
    app_id,
    count(*) filter(where event_type = 'store_app_view') app_views,
    count(*) filter(where event_type = 'store_app_install') app_installs
    count(*) filter(where event_type = 'store_app_install')
        / count(*) filter(where event_type = 'store_app_view') app_conversion_rate
from events_db
group by app_id
```

Implementing the logic to infer store installs for old versions of the app is a bit more complex. For this, one method is to use window functions:

```
select
    app_id,
    count(*) filter(where event_type = 'store_app_view') app_views,
    count(*) filter(where event_type = 'store_app_install' or event_type = 'store_app_view' and lead_event_type = 'store_app_download') app_installs
    count(*) filter(where event_type = 'store_app_install' or event_type = 'store_app_view' and lead_event_type = 'store_app_download')
        / count(*) filter(where event_type = 'store_app_View') app_conversion_rate

from (
    select
        e.*,
        lead(event_type) over(partition by user_id order by event_type) lead_event_type
    from events_db e
) t
group by app_id
```

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks a lot! store installs of old version of the appstore was making me quite confused.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL it will be near the same as @GMB shown for Postgres

```sql
SELECT
    `app_id`,
    SUM(`event_type` = 'store_app_view') app_views,
    SUM(`event_type` = 'store_app_install') app_installs,
    (SUM(`event_type` = 'store_app_install') / SUM(`event_type` = 'store_app_view')) app_conversion_rate
FROM `events_db`
GROUP BY `app_id`
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o8JoQHDxdLoSRrvMhoveMe/1